# jQuery difference between $(document).ready and $().ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on some code I didn't write. I'm trying to comprehend it as fully as possible. I've been using jQuery for just some months so I'm pretty familiar with it but not an expert; I tried to ask google this question but I didn't find anything.

In two different parts of my code I have the following statements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        //function to be executed
    });
```

and

```
$().ready(function() {
            //function to be executed
    });
```

What are the differences between them? Are they the same thing? I have read about jQuery selectors, but I was wondering what empty brackets could mean.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the syntax are equivalent and perform the same task.

> jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready. All of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

```
$( handler )
$( document ).ready( handler )
$( "document" ).ready( handler )
$( "img" ).ready( handler )
$().ready( handler )
```

However as per the docs except the first method all others are depreciated, so you should stick with that only.

You can refer this [link](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more info

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!